# ASP.NET MVC Access JavaScript Variable from within code block

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a code block in some JavaScript on a razor page. Just before the code block I have a normal JavaScript variable. How do I access this variable from withing the Code Block?

[image: CodeBlock]

Comment: Hi there. It would be preferable to paste your code as text. That way your post will be smaller on the SO servers and it will be searchable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive you could use `@:`

Something like this:

```
if(context.Project.Find("ProjectId"){
     @:actionToTake = "ProjectOutcome";
}
```

or the special text-tag

```
if(context.Project.Find("ProjectId"){
     <text>actionToTake = "ProjectOutcome";</text>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how about in the following:


`$("#next-step").click(function () {
            document.location.href = "@Url.Action("Read", actionToTake, new { ProjectId = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["ProjectId"] }, null)";
        });`

Comment: I would put the url in a separate variable outside the click-function. Then insert it as the href with @variablename

Comment: Yes, should have thought of that sooner. That negates the need for the `actionToTake` in the first place